# How do we assign Categorical Codes for the data that is coming new?

Tags: modeling

I am building a model on a large dataset.

My Model actually involves converting the Categorical Columns into Categorical Codes. My Model gets Trained after the conversion happens.

There is a new single of data that is coming up and I want to predict the output of this new line using my Model.

If I apply Categorical Codes to this, then this will look completely different from the ones that my model got trained towards -

For Example :- Age 10 might have had a categorical code of 1 while building the model (considering it changes according to the sample of the data) and now in the new line it could be evaluated as 0.

How much of this change in categorical code is going to affect my  model & how do we go about solving this or nullify this from happening?

Comment: Are you getting new categories in an existing variables, or are the labels of the categories changing between train time and test time?

Comment: @MatthewDrury No, I am not getting new categories in existing variables. They are never changing during train and test and now let's say it's in production. When a new single of data comes in - the categorical codes for this new line of data would be totally different from the same data assuming to be present in the train data right ?